# Redmine 2.1.2 + Gitolite setup - "rake aborted!" on "rake db:migrate_plugins"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, ubuntu-12.04, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to setup a testing server with Redmine and GIT. I'm following this series of tutorials:

- [Setting up a Centralized Git Service](http://paulsalcido.com/2012/06/15/setting-up-a-centralized-git-service/)
- [Setting up the Redmine Front End](http://paulsalcido.com/2012/06/16/setting-up-the-redmine-front-end/)
- [Integrating Redmine and Gitolite](http://paulsalcido.com/2012/06/18/integrating-redmine-and-gitolite/)
- [Fully Automating the Redmine Gitolite Integration](http://paulsalcido.com/2012/06/24/fully-automating-the-redmine-gitolite-integration/)

I'm installing the Gitolite plugin for Redmine, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I follow all the instructions, but when i run `rake db:migrate_plugins` I get this error:

```
/usr/share/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate_plugins --trace
rake aborted!
GONE
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:191:in `deprecate'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rdoctask.rb:4
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:5:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:5
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks.rb:15
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/tasks.rb:6
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:292:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:292:in `initialize_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:424:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:7
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:581:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:87:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:86:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

Before that, I had to do some variations:

- I've installed the plugin into `/usr/share/redmine/plugins` instead of `/usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins`.
- I've run `bundle install` so it installs some missing dependencies.

And I don't know what's next. I've been reading the docs over and over, but this seems to be a Ruby/Rails versioning problem out of my control.

I'm running Rails 3.2.8, Redmine 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 from PPAs. Perhaps I should stop trying these versions and go for old good Rails 2.3.14 and Redmine 1.3.2?

Comment: I'm the original author of those tutorials - it's unfortunate that in six months the value of that tutorial can go down so fast.  I'll see if I can't get some time to update and experiment outside of the fact - in addition, I have far more RoR experience now than I did in the past, but I have a lot of other assignments.  Hopefully someone here has an answer.  Still, it looks like it might be placement of the database migration file - like it is expecting it to be in vendor/plugins, hence the 'GONE' statement.  Just a guess at this point.

Comment: Thank you, the tutorials are very well explained and were very useful to understand all this environment. Now, putting the plugin on vendor/plugins shouts a warning, that's the reason to strip out the vendor directory. Probably the Gitolite plugin won't work with Rails 2.3.14 and Redmine 1.3.2 and that's all. I'll try going back to Redmine 1.x and Rails 2.x.

Comment: Yeah, the gitolite plugin is quite old.  Perhaps I'll take a look around for a newer one, as my current workload prevents me from forking and fixing this one.